# How do I minimize global error across multiple image homographies?

Tags: computer-vision, homography, image-stitching, levenberg-marquardt

I am stitching together multiple images with arbitrary 3D views of a planar surface. I have some estimation of which images overlap and a coarse estimate of each pairwise homography between pairs of overlapping images. However, I need to refine my homographies by minimizing the global error across all images.

I have read a few different papers with various methods for doing this, and I think the best way would be to use a non-linear optimization such as Levenberg–Marquardt, ideally in a fast way that is sparse and/or parallel.

Ideally I would like to use an existing library such as sba or pba, but I am really confused as to how to limit the calculation to just estimating the eight parameters of the homography rather than the full 3 dimensions for both camera pose and object position. I also found [this handy explanation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dyer/ai-qual/szeliski-tr06.pdf) by Szeliski (see section 5.1 on page 50) but again, the math is all for a rotating camera rather than a flat surface.

How do I use L-M to minimize the global error for a set of homographies? Is there a speedy way to do this with existing bundle adjustment libraries?

Note: I cannot use methods that rely on rotation-only camera motion (such as in openCV) because those cannot accurately estimate camera poses, and I also cannot use full 3D reconstruction methods (such as SfM) because those have too many parameters which results in non-planar point clouds. I definitely need something specific to a full 8 parameter homography. Camera intrinsics don't really matter because I am already correcting those in an earlier step.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use Szeliski approach with an infinity focal length?

Comment: No, I think not because the Szeliski approach reduces the number of variables by removing the translation component. I have very large translations and small rotations, so I am pretty sure the rotation only model would just give me garbage (and I have seen posts by other people who have tried this with openCV and it fails).